# Detach local database .mdf, copy, attach the new file

Tags: c#, sql-server, local, detach

I tried to detach my local database .mdf copy it in another folder and attach the new file at launch and copy to the older folder when closing.

It seems to works at launch but i have an error when the form closing :

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProgramData\MyData\db1.mdf' because it is being used by another process.

That's my code :

```
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DetachDatabase();
        CopyDb();
        AttachDatabase();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Data.MyNewFolder);    
    }


    public static bool DetachDatabase()
    {
        try
        {

            string connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("exec sp_detach_db '{0}'", "db1");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("exec sp_detach_db '{0}'", "db2");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            } 
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool AttachDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("exec sys.sp_attach_db    db1,    'db1.mdf'");
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("exec sys.sp_attach_db    db2,    'db2.mdf'");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void Frm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        LocalDB.DetachDatabase();
        CopyDb();
        LocalDB.AttachDatabase();
    }
```

what is the good way for do it ?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server is a **server-based** database system - so the **best way** is to ***NOT*** fiddle around with the `.mdf` files and just leave the database **on the server** and connect to it and use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch to `master` and put the target database offline

**WARNING**: Use at your own risk (e.g. can you use `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`?)

```
var commandText = string.Format(@"
    USE MASTER;
    ALTER DATABASE {0} SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true';", "db1");
```

The second parameter to `sp_detach_db` just avoids statistics update (would be faster)

You can now safely move the `mdf` and `ldf` files from their original location

Assuming your database is already offline and you have moved your `db1.mdf` file into `D:\Whatever`, I think you can do this ( **I didn't test it, beware** )

```
var commandText = string.Format(@"
    USE MASTER;
    ALTER DATABASE {0}
      MODIFY FILE (
        NAME = '{0}',
        FILENAME = 'D:\Wherever\{0}.mdf');
    ALTER DATABASE {0} SET ONLINE;", "db1");
```

Comment: for the closing the db is still attached but i found thid for for doing it 
 var start = new ProcessStartInfo("sqllocaldb", "stop MSSQLLocalDB");
            start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            using (var stop = Process.Start(start))
                stop.WaitForExit();
            start.Arguments = "delete MSSQLLocalDB";
            using (var delete = Process.Start(start))
                delete.WaitForExit();

Comment: I'm wondering if there's no way to force the DB to be fully detached  before the call returns (e.g. set single user mode, go back to multi user after re-attach). Restarting the process doesn't feel the right thing to do, but, well... :D Aslo, if this is your main form, why not detaching/attaching after the form is fully destroyed (and also before it's constructed) instead of using an event handler?