# How to properly detach a MSSQL database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to copy a MDF file using PowerShell.

I take the DB offline and detach it using this SQL (based on [Detach local database .mdf, copy, attach the new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205434/detach-local-database-mdf-copy-attach-the-new-file)):

```sql
USE MASTER;
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
EXEC sp_detach_db 'mydatabase'
```

This sometimes gives the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot detach the database'mydatabase' because it is currently in use.

How to properly detach the database?

Comment: I guess you would want to set skipchecks to true. --> `EXEC sp_detach_db 'mydatabase', 'true'`
Or if you are doing it via SSMS, then make sure you check the `Drop connections` option.

Comment: Just found the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Should set the db to `SINGLE_USER` before detaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to close outstanding connections to the database by setting it to `SINGLE_USER` mode:

```
USE master;  
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

As described here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The difference between your first and second command is that the first closes all the connections and the second leaves the only one. Both of them use WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE. If you say that the first sometimes fail it means it does not do ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE. The same can do your second command, I mean, if the first may fail, the second can do it either